# Updating Record EF not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Why is this not updating in the database, but the commented out version does work?

```
public bool InsertOrUpdateItems(Items item)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
            {
                var items = dbContext.Items.Find(item.ItemId);
                if (items != null)
                {
                    dbContext.Items.Attach(items);
                    dbContext.Entry(items).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    //dbContext.Entry(items).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
```

There are no exceptions being thrown, it just wont update.  Even though the record is found.

Comment: Are the values that are not updating simple properties or part of a larger object graph?

Comment: simple values that change --  the changes are reflected in the 'item' variable being passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line in question is commented out, there are no new values to update. Notice that you:

1. Get object named `items` from DB
2. You attach it (although it is attached by default)
3. You try to save the same `items`

Object that you pass as a parameter for InsertOrUpdateItems method (`item`) is not even touched in your code, except reading its Id for use with Find()

Comment: The line commented out works, I found that as a workaround, I have never used the CurrentValues property.

Comment: OK, where do you use object `item` from the first line of your code? Nowhere except the commented out line. That's why it works only with this line

Comment: Yea I see it, going to check now